# How to git clone multiple repos into an existing repo?

Tags: git, github

Assuming there are three repos containing the files below:

1. git@github.com:me/project.git

   ```
   code/file1
   code/file2
   code/file3
   ```
2. git@github.com:me/extras1.git

   ```
   code/file4
   code/file5
   code/file6
   ```
3. git@github.com:me/extras2.git

   ```
   code/file7
   code/file8
   code/file9
   ```

So far I have cloned **project.git**, so I have the following directory structure:

```
project/code/file1
project/code/file2
project/code/file3
```

How would you clone (or merge?) **extras1.git** and **extras2.git** so that you end up with the directory structure below AND still be able to do a `git pull` for each repo:

```
project/code/file1
project/code/file2
project/code/file3
project/code/file4
project/code/file5
project/code/file6
project/code/file7
project/code/file8
project/code/file9
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will do it (assuming each repo has a single branch called "master")

```
git remote add extras1 git@github.com:me/extras1.git
git fetch extras1
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories extras1/master
git remote add extras2 git@github.com:me/extras2.git
git fetch extras2
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories extras2/master
```

Comment: Did you mean to type "extras2.git" on the 4th line? Also, after running these commands, will I still be able to do `git pull` for each of the three repos (since they are managed separately)?